# How to make footer responsive with images

Tags: html, css

I am working on a footer where I did use some images but the problem is I can not make images responsive.

I don't have enough experience in frontend if anyone can give an idea or little help will really appreciate. I use bootstrap.

Here is what I've tried so far.

**HTML:**

```
<div className="clearfix" />
    <footer className="footer">
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="text-left">
                <img src="https://tssg.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Irelands_EU_ESIF_2014_2020_en.png"
                     alt="European Structural and Investment Funds" />
                <img src="https://tssg.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/european-union-logo.png"
                     alt="European Regional Development Fund" />
                <img src="https://tssg.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/HEA_Grey.png"
                     alt="Higher Education Authority Ireland" />
                <img src="https://tssg.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/EI.png"
                     alt="Enterprise Ireland Logo" />
                <img src="https://tssg.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/sfi-logo.png"
                     alt="Science Foundation Ireland Logo" />
                <span className="text-right">Copyright © 2019</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.footer {
    bottom: 0px;
    color: #272727;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 200px;
    //background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(223, 223, 255);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    background-color: #ede9e9;
    // background:#33444a;ede9e9
}

.footer img {
    border: none !important;
    width: auto !important;
    max-height: 28px !important;
    cursor: pointer;
}

    .footer img:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 50px ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1. You should use `class="classes here"` instead of `className="classes here"` in your HTML.
2. In your CSS add `height:auto` and `max-width:100%` to your .footer img class like so:

   `.footer img {
       border: none !important;
       width: auto !important;
       height:auto;
       max-width:100%;
       max-height: 28px !important;
       cursor: pointer;
     }`

That should make the images responsive.

Comment: sorry for not mentioning I am using in react that's why className instead of class
thanks for your help really appreciate but  the helping code you provided isn't working

Comment: Hmm, works for me...? The images shrink and remain proportional on smaller screens, see https://codepen.io/friendlywp/pen/LKXNmZ

Comment: but without adding height:auto; max-width:100%; stay same

Comment: Yes, you have to change the code to make it work. Can you not change the code?

Answer (score 0):

Add class "img-responsive" for BootStrap 3 and Add class "img-fluid" for BootStrap 4.
Example:

```
<img src="https://tssg.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/sfi-logo.png" alt="Science Foundation Ireland Logo" class="img-responsive" />
```

Hope this helps.